# Receive a collections of Files and a list of key:value in the same HTTP POST request

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, postman, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm working on VisualStudio 2017 and I created a ASP.NET Core Web Api project.

I need to catch a collections of files and somethings more together in the same HTTP POST request

I have a controller like this :

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Upload(IFormFileCollection files, Dictionary<string, 
object> tags)
{
   // whatever code ......
}
```

I know how do I get a collections of files with IFormFileCollection, but when I need to get both IFormFileCollection and somethings more like a IEnumerable of "key:value" pair like the code above, I get stuck.

I'm using the tool POSTMAN but i don't know how to create a request that work with my controller. I am not obligated to use POSTMAN, it's just the one I know.

Comment: Inside Postman, if your application is running it would be whatever URL Visual Studio assigned when it deployed IIS Express to host the application.  You would simply put that url inside Postman: `localhost:666/Home/SubmitForm`. The site will follow an Controller then Action, so HomeController with a SubmitForm Action would be called.  So you can see the request.  You'll have to actually build your array of `FormData()` objects to correctly test inside Postman.  Meaning you manually build the object in Postman.

Comment: If I send only a collections of files and my controller suppose receive only IFormFileCollection, that's ok, my controller work fine. The problem appears when I try to send somethings more because I don't be sure how do I do it with POSTMAN and then I don't know which parameter I need to have in my controller to be available to get its.

Comment: I'm not sure you can have more than one parameter in an `HttpPost` method unless you specify some as `[FromBody]` and others as `[FromUri]`

Comment: As long as I can get all parameter that I need it's doesn't matter whether I got to put [FromBody]. The thing is that I don't know how do I should build the request in POSTMAN to reach my goal.

Comment: @Guille I told you, you have to manually build your form data inside Postman as an array.